# UIlabel text alignment for ipad and iphone

Tags: ios, uilabel, universal

I am working on a universal app which has one label. When I rotate the screen, the label text alignment becomes different.

Comment: can you post some more information? Screenshot or alike? How do they differ? Do you have the code at hand?

Comment: Axel i cant post the scree shot and code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void) handleRotations:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)paramSender{
 if (self.helloWorldLabel == nil){
}
return;
/* Take the previous rotation and add the current rotation to it */
self.helloWorldLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(self.rotationAngleInRadians +
paramSender.rotation);
/* At the end of the rotation, keep the angle for later use */ if (paramSender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
}
self.rotationAngleInRadians += paramSender.rotation;
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you set the auto-resizing property for the `UILabel` properly